# LU decomposition using matlab's linsolve

Tags: matlab, decomposition

So i'm trying to solve a system of linear equations using LU decomposition. I made a code in matlab that i'm comparing with the output of matlab's linsolve. The thing that's confussing me is this:
As far as i understand (from what i learned from this site: http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-linear-system.html) Lu decomposition works by decomposing A into L(lower triangular) and U (upper triangular). And then it calculates x solving two equations:
B = L*Y;
Y = U*X;

So my confussion comes here.

If i do x_solutions=linsolve(A,B), i get a different result that if i do x=linsolve(U,y) (of course doing first y = linsolve(L,B)).

Does someone know why this happens? shouldn't x be equal to x_solutions in this case or am i missing something?

Just for the sake of giving away all the information this is how i'm doing it:

```
A=[1 2 6; 1 2 2; 2 2 1];
B=[1 0 1]';

G=linsolve(A,B);

UPP = triu(A);
LOW= tril(A);

y=linsolve(LOW,B);
x=linsolve(UPP,y);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/6163/matrix-decompositions#t=201609240746034184022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`triu` and `tril` do not give you the L and U in LU decomposition.

They just give entries lower/upper part of matrix, i.e.,

```
A == LOW + UPP - diag(A)
```

`diag(A)` is subtracted because both `LOW` and `UPP` have diagonal part of `A`

In LU decomposition, L and U should satisfy

```
A == L*U
```

If you want to get such `L` and `U`, use

```
[L,U] = lu(A);
```